# Why do I get same addresses in 2D array?

Tags: c, arrays, memory-address

Recently I came to this problem, when assigning values to 2D array. To represent my problem I created small C code. I am using QT creator (community) 3.3.0 and minGW 4.9.1 32bit.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
double m[2][2];
for (int i = 0 ; i<3; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
         printf("%p[%d][%d]     ", (void*)&m[i][j],i,j);
    printf("\n");
 }
return 0;
}
```

As output I get memory addresses

```
0028FE98[0][0]     0028FEA0[0][1]     0028FEA8[0][2]
0028FEA8[1][0]     0028FEB0[1][1]     0028FEB8[1][2]
0028FEB8[2][0]     0028FEC0[2][1]     0028FEC8[2][2]
```

You can see that there are same addresses for non-equal array items. So when I assign value to for example [1][2], value in [2][0] changes too.

Please give me any advice on how to solve this. Thank you very much.

Comment: `i<3`,`j<3`  --> `i<2`,`j<2`, `m` has 4 elements(m[0][0],m[0][1],m[1][0],m[1][1])

Comment: Those are not valid addresses for the array you declared. What BLUEPIXY means is that `m[2][2]` is a 2x2 matrix, not 3x3, so for example m[1][2] is not valid, since only valid indexes are 0 and 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your array should either be 3x3:

```
double m[3][3];
```

Or your loop should only iterate twice, not three times.

The code you have now accesses some out of bounds memory, causing undefined behaviour.

Comment: Well it worked, thank you. But sill I just realised I do not understand 2D arrays than. I thought that when I created m[2][2] i could access idexes 0,1 and 2. So this would mean I have an 3x3 array. So can you clarify how is it working? Does it work from 1 not 0? Or better said do I put number of elements when declaring array like int m[number of elements][number of elements]?

Comment: @Peter It starts counting from `0`, but it only has `2` elements, IE `double m[3]` has 3 elements: `m[0]`, `m[1]`, and `m[2]`. While `double d[2][2]` has 4 elements: `d[0][0]`, `d[0][1]`, `d[1][0]`, and `d[1][1]`. If you go out of bounds and access something like `d[2][0]` that will result in undefined behaviour, in your case it was just accessing the next element in the array `d[1][0]`, but it could have also caused a segmentation fault, or even an animation of a pineapple running a marathon.

Comment: You might remember, from your C class, that arrays in C are accessed by indexes that range from 0 to (numArrayElements-1)   In other words, the valid access offsets for the array are: m[0...1][0...1] for an array defined as m[2][2]

Answer (score 1):

You have wrong `for` conditions. Should be `i<2` and `j<2`. Try and you'll se that all will be ok.

And why there're same pointers? Because table(1d, 2d, 3d don't matter) in memory is one memory block. All dimensions are "in one line" and when you write something like this

```
double tab[2][2];

tab[0][1] = 1; // that's the same as *(tab + 0*sizeof(double)*2 + 1*sizeof(double)) = 1;
tab[1][1] = 2; // that's the same as *(tab + 1*sizeof(double)*2 + 1*sizeof(double)) = 2;
```

So you can see that you have this

```
double m[2][2];

m[1][2]  // that's the same as (m + 1*sizeof(double)*2 + 2*sizeof(double)) => (m + 4*sizeof(double)) ;
m[2][0]  // that's the same as (m + 2*sizeof(double)*2 + 0*sizeof(double)) => (m + 4*sizeof(double));
```

That's why that was the same pointers

Answer (score 1):

Your array size is too small.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
double m[3][3]; // <------ Change size to 3,3
for (int i = 0 ; i<3; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
         printf("%p[%d][%d]     ", (void*)&m[i][j],i,j);
    printf("\n");
 }
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you declare m[2][2] to have 2 rows of 2, valid indexes are 0 and 1
if you want a 3x3 array you have to declare

```
double m[3][3];
```